# Killing process with subprocess strange behaviour.

Tags: python, subprocess, kill

I am experiencing something quite strange and I can not see what it is going on. I am calling the following three commands, and they are supposed to kill all the processes that contain `flowServer`, `learningServer`and `collectCounters` in the name. However, only flow servers get killed.

```
subprocess.call("sudo kill -9 $(ps aux | grep 'flowServer' | awk '{print $2}')", shell=True)
subprocess.call("sudo kill -9 $(ps aux | grep 'learningServer' | awk '{print $2}')", shell=True)
subprocess.call("sudo kill -9 $(ps aux | grep 'collectCounters' | awk '{print $2}')", shell=True)
```

But if I call a python script that includes exactly the lines above it works!!

```
subprocess.call("sudo python stopServers.py", shell=True)
```

What is going on?

Comment: Did you call the original Python script as root?

Comment: Not likely related, but do you have access to `pkill`?

Comment: That, or `killall`

Comment: You're either having permission issues (maybe sudo is only working for the first line) or `ps aux | grep 'learningServer'` isn't returning what you expect.

Comment: The code you posted works fine for me; I'm not sure what's going on.

Comment: I am executing it as root. And "ps axu | grep 'learningServer' should return what I expect, since when I call it from the `stopServers.py` script it works. I have to say that all the commands above are executed in a namespace, but not sure if that is relevant since from the root namespace I can see all the processes.

Comment: I just found now that If I remove all the `subprocess.call` from my program the same happens. And this is due to flowServer has a handle for SIGTERM. But what I don't is why the `kill -9` does not do anything when the program does it, but it works from the shell...

Comment: Even more strange:  `ps axu | grep 'something'` is does not detect the processes when I ran it inside the script but from shell it does it... So `ps axu ` is the problem.